# Codeigniter: URI segments

Tags: codeigniter

How do I create an if statement saying something like this?
Basically, how do you use the URI class to determine if there is a value in any segment?

```
$segment = value_of_any_segment;
if($segment == 1{
    do stuff
}
```

I know this is pretty elementary, but I don't totally understand the URI class...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear to me, but I'll try to help. Are you wondering how to determine if a particular segment exists or if it contains a specific value?

As you are probably aware, you can use the [URI class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html) to access the specific URI segments. Using `yoursite.com/blog/article/123` as an example, `blog` is the 1st segment, `article` is the 2nd segment, and `123` is the 3rd segment. You access each using `$this->uri->segment(n)`

You then can construct if statements like this:

```
// if segment 2 exists ("articles" in the above example), do stuff
if ($this->uri->segment(2)) {
    // do stuff
}

// if segment 3 ("123" in the above example) is equal to some value, do stuff
if ($this->uri->segment(3) == $myValue) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if not and I can elaborate or provide additional information.

**Edit:**

If you need to determine if a particular string appears *in any segment* of the URI, you can do something like this:

```
// get the entire URI (using our example above, this is "/blog/article/123")
$myURI = $this->uri->uri_string()

// the string we want to check the URI for
$myString = "article";    

// use strpos() to search the entire URI for $myString
// also, notice we're using the "!==" operator here; see note below
if (strpos($myURI, $myString) !== FALSE) {
    // "article" exists in the URI
} else {
    // "article" does not exist in the URI
}
```

A note regarding [strpos()](http://us.php.net/strpos) (from the PHP documentation):

> This function may return Boolean
>   FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to
>   FALSE, such as 0 or "". Please read
>   the section on Booleans for more
>   information. Use the === operator for
>   testing the return value of this
>   function.

I hope my edit helps. Let me know if I can elaborate.

Comment: Thanks, Colin!  You're on the right track!  Your answer solves my problem, but I'm wondering if it's possible to use uri_to_assoc(n)?

Comment: @Kevin: Can you elaborate? Are you trying to determine if a particular string exists in *any segment* of the URL?

Comment: @Kevin: I updated my answer to address that. Let me know if it isn't clear.

Comment: You've been most helpful!  Thanks!